# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Test1, int

Tags: java

I have little problem with my Java code. I'm using code below but Eclipse always prompting same message "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Test1, int".But if i change the code into "System.out.println(test1+""+100);" or "System.out.println(""+100+test1);" or "System.out.println(100+""+test1);",there was no problem.

Anyone having an idea about it? Please help. Thank you so much;

```
public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {

Test1 test1=new Test1("abc",12);
System.out.println(test1+100+"");//this is where i got the error!
//all three lines below got no problems.
//System.out.println(test1+""+100);
//System.out.println(""+100+test1);
//System.out.println(100+""+test1);
}

}
class Test1
{
 private int age;
 private String name;
 public Test1(){}
 public Test1(String name,int age)
 {
     this.name=name;
     this.age=age;
 } 
 public String toString()
 {
     return name+""+age;

 }
 }
```

Comment: Try `System.out.println(test1.toString() + 100 + "");`

Comment: Did you implement toString method in your Test1? If yes then look at @pzaenger comment

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that is illegal.

Because you are trying to add an object and an integer value which is not possible in real world. But when you do

```
test1+ ""+ 100
```

The whole thing got changed to string concatination and when you adding an object and string, the toString method of that object gets called and added to the string.

So looks like you want to add something from the object to the given value. So get that value from the object and then sum it up.

```
System.out.println(test1.getAge()+100+""); // have getAge implemented
```

Or if you want to print the whole thing use the implemented toString and then sum it up.

as a side note, when you do not use concatenation, and just pass the plain object, toString method gets called and prints the object.

```
System.out.println(test1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support operator overloading ***except*** for a few limited cases, all I can think of deal with `String` concatenation. You **can** do

```
System.out.println(test1.toString() + 100 + "");
```

Your other legal examples involve `String` concatenation as well (when then first term is a `String` it *promotes* the other terms - and of course `String` + `Object` or `String` + `int` is only possible because the Java language/runtime explicitly allows operator overloading for `String`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the compiler said, the `+` operator is not defined for the `Test1` class. It's only defined for `String`s (concatenation) and numeric types (addition).

If the first operand of the `+` operator is neither a `String` nor a numeric type, the compiler doesn't know what to do.

On the other hand, if the first operand is a `String`, the compiler treats the operator as `String` concatenation, and converts your `Test1` instance (the second operand) to a `String` by calling `toString()`.

Therefore

```
System.out.println(""+100+test1);
```

works.

The following would also work:

```
System.out.println(""+test1+100);
```

or

```
System.out.println(test1.toString()+100);
```